# Showing Json data in asp.net's datagridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, datagridview

```
Im need to showing json data in asp.net's gridview (not html table) . I search a lot but i cant figure it out. I got code like this.


 function BindGridView() {
        //Tabloyu oluşturma
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $(".mainGridView").empty();
                    $(".mainGridView").append('<tr><td class="' + i + '">' + data[i].name + '</td>'
                           + '<td>' + data[i].username + '</td></tr>');
                };



            },

            error: function (msg) {

                alert(msg.responseText);
            }
        })
    };
```

---

```
<body onload="BindGridView();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView class="mainGridView" runat="server"  />
        here it s style codes
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
</form>
```

I tried showing json data in html table it was worked same logic but in this case didnt help me.
When i run  this code  it gives me no error at console screen and it shows nothing on browser it's clean page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GridView` control won't render on the page unless you set a `DataSource` for it, this means the **GridView doesn't even appear on the page**.So your AJAX call is working 100% and getting the JSON back but it can't find the GridView control to bind to.

To overcome this issue you can just set your `GridView` bound to an empty `DataSource`:

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        mainGridView.DataSource = new List<string>() { };
        mainGridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            BindGridView();
            function BindGridView() {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(".mainGridView").empty();
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $(".mainGridView").append('<tr><td class="' + i + '">' + data[i].name + '</td>'
                                   + '<td>' + data[i].username + '</td></tr>');
                        };
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.responseText);
                    }
                })
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="mainGridView" runat="server" CssClass="mainGridView" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No records found">
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Output:**

[image: Displaying AJAX call results in ASP.NET GridView]